# How to check in .net core 6 if a google token brings my GOOGLE API credentials?

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

How can I verify if a Google Api token that comes from any frontend to my .net core 6 api is enabled with my idCliente credentials.

example:

```
var validPayload = await GoogleJsonWebSignature.ValidateAsync(idToken);
```

This method works and verifies that it is an active token and that the session is active. but it does not tell me that it belongs to my authorized accounts in my system, how can I know that it is not token of any other credentials.

I am using `nuget Google.Apis.Auth;` and in my configuration it never requests client id or Secret client id

I just need to know how to check if the google token is correct and if it was generated in a proprietary application. and not any other.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstanding what an ID Token is used for.  The ID token will just verify that the user who logged in is in fact the owner of your account. It doesn't contain anything about the client that was used to create it.

You can decrypt the JWT (for example via https://jwt.io/) and you will see the claims within the JWT:

```
{
  "iss": "https://accounts.google.com",
  "azp": "407408718192.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "aud": "407408718192.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "sub": "[redacted]",
  "email": "[redacted]",
  "email_verified": true,
  "at_hash": "GPbfw-jQOI3ulbmuO-pi2A",
  "name": "Linda Lawton",
  "picture": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/AEdFTp46WTOIbHj5Nl1VJRFf4Izj9YrX61i75F16H1qSA1Q=s96-c",
  "given_name": "Linda",
  "family_name": "Lawton",
  "locale": "en",
  "iat": 1674548618,
  "exp": 1674552218
}
```

Neither a refresh token or an access token can be decrypted in this manner.

If you want to verify that a refresh token for example was created with your client ID you can by trying to refresh it.

If you want to verify that an access token works just try to use it.